# WPF Data trigger to apply style on parent element

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I have a Grid which contains a Scrollviewer. I would like to change the Grid's margin if the Vertical scrollbar is visible.

```
<Grid x:Name="TopGrid" Margin="50,10,100,10" Background="Gainsboro"  >
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="sv" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Text="Description" />
         </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The DataTrigger condition in Scrollviewer should be this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility,
                                        ElementName=sv}" Value="Visible">
</DataTrigger>
```

and the grid's style should be changed to this:

```
<Setter TargetName="TopGrid" Property="Margin" Value="100"/>
```

How can I have the data trigger binding on Scrollviewer and change the style of the parent grid?

Thanks

Comment: so where is this `DataTrigger` at the moment?

Comment: Nowhere. I am just indicating what the condition and the style should be. But by default this data trigger that has a target to ScrollViewer could not set the Style to the parent Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change `Grid.Margin` based on some condition you could create `Style` for `Grid` with `Trigger` you posted but you need to move default `Margin` value into `Setter` otherwise `DataTrigger` won't be able to change that value

```
<Grid x:Name="TopGrid" Background="Gainsboro">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,10,100,10"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=sv, Path=ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="Visible">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="100"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="sv" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Text="Description" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! Based on your solution, is there a way to apply this condition to all Scrollviewers and not only the Scrollviewer with name "sv"?

Comment: I don't see how. In current solution it triggers on specific element. You could use either `MultiBinding` (with converter) or `MultiDataTrigger` but you would have specify which `ScrollViewer` you would like to check. Other way you'll end up with many `ScrollViewer` fighting to set parent `Margin`

Comment: Yes you are right. However I can see that if the Scrollviewer and the Textblock are placed inside a separate UserControl, and the Grid will contain this UserControl, the trigger is not working. The "ElementName" works only for the elements in current control?

Comment: `UserControl` is completely different name scope. Names from within `UserControl` are not visible outside. You would need to create some proxy `DependencyProperty` in `UserControl` to make `ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility` accessible from outside